# How to implement max length on number input in for loop condition

Tags: javascript, express

I am building out a simple express app to solve the FizzBuzz question and I have been told to "Write a server using a framework that you are familiar with that accepts a GET request in the form of
GET http://localhost:3000/fizzbuzz/N
**Where N is any number up to five digits.**

How do I limit the number being passed in to 5 digits?
This is what I have so far ..

```
  app.get('/fizzbuzz/:n', (req, res) => {
  // request params for number being passed in
  let fizzbuzz = [`${req.params.n}`];
  let result;
  // use for loop to iterate through number passed in and return proper response
  for (let i = 1; i < 99999; i++) {
    if (fizzbuzz % 3 === 0) {
      if (fizzbuzz % 5 === 0) {
        console.log('FizzBuzz');
        result = 'FizzBuzz';
      } else if (fizzbuzz % 3 === 0) {
        console.log('Fizz');
        result = 'Fizz';
      }
    } else if (fizzbuzz % 5 === 0) {
      console.log('Buzz');
      result = 'Buzz';
    } else {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
  res.send(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually limit the passed number in the url, but you could actually add a condition so if the number is more than 5 digits it will send an error or something like that.

**Here's a solution:**

1. You need actually to check if `req.params.n` is an integer, you can actaully use `try/catch` and `parseInt()` but i prefer to use `string.matches("[0-9]+")` so if it returns true that means its an integer.
2. After checking the first condition, just check `string.length` if its bigger than five then you should return an error or display a message to the user saying that he exceeded the limit.

Answer (score 0):

To check if n is greater than five digits, you can just check if it is greater than 99999. To do this check, you could add some type of validation middleware like express-validator or just do an if and return a 400 or 422 error yourself.

Additionally, I am assuming any question like this would want you to return a string where each line is the number, fizz, buzz, or fizzbuzz, not the single value for the last number.

As just a fun idea since you have a max value, it wouldn't take up that much space to just pre-calc all the fizzbuzz values and store them in your database and turn this whole route into a really simple db query.

```
 app.get('/fizzbuzz/:n', (req, res) => {
  
  if(req.params.n > 99999){
    res.status(422).send({
    message: 'Invalid parameter must be 5 digits or under'
   });
  }

  let result = '';
  for (let i = 1; i <= req.params.n; i++) {
    let line =''
    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      if (i % 5 === 0) {
        line = 'FizzBuzz';
      } else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        line = 'Fizz';
      }
    } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
      line = 'Buzz';
    } else {
     line = i;
    }
    result += line+'/n';
  }
  res.send(result);
});
```